# Enable JMXRemote monitoring

Tags: java, solaris, jvisualvm

OS=Solaris 5.1

Java=1.6.0_101-b14

I'm having an issue with a java email daemon and want to monitor it via Java VisualVM.  I have modified my script to enable jmxremote monitoring.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=15000 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
```

I have a connection to the remote host, but when I create the jmxconnection, I am prompted for credentials despite the authenticate=false.  I don't have access to the java directories, so I created the jmxremote.access and jmxremote.password files locally and added the following:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=<local dir> \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=<local dir> \
```

I get the same behavior.  In neither case my credentials do not work.  Is there something within Java or the OS that may be forcing authentication?

TIA

Comment: Solaris 5.1?  Are you sure that's correct?  That version is absolutely ancient, and I seriously doubt it can run Java 1.6.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong.  I'm just getting back into the Unix world after being out for 15 years.  Apparently one or two things have changed.  It is SunOS 5.1, Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10s_u10wos_17b SPARC.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Right before you try to connect remotely, put the Java process under `truss` with `truss -f -a -vall -l -d -o /path/to/output/file -p PID`, where PID is the process ID of the Java process you're trying to debug.  Then try to connect.  That should capture the JVM's response to your remote connection attempt, and reveal what it's actually doing.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew.  I ended up stumbling down a slightly different path.  As I was digging around looking for answers, I came across this site, http://support.sas.com/kb/41/565.html.  Following this setup and adding the following to my local management.properties:

    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=15000

 all the java processes popped up in VisualVM without having to do any of the original configurations.  Thanks again for your assistance and I'll definitely be keeping the truss info handy.